# No mouse press/release events on mouse double click

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, pyside, pyside2

I want to use both events: `mouseDoubleClick` and `mouseReleaseEvent`. But there is an issue: The latter event is always triggered even when one double clicks the mouse.

Answer (score 1):

Answer is here below. Please post suggestions to help me improve this code.

```py
from PySide2.QtCore import qApp, QTimer
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget


class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.timer = QTimer(self)
        self.timer.setSingleShot(True)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.single_click)
        self.double_click_interval = qApp.doubleClickInterval()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, e):
        if not self.timer.isActive():
            self.timer.start(self.double_click_interval)
        else:
            self.timer.stop()
            self.double_click()
        super().mouseReleaseEvent(e)

    def single_click(self):
        print("single")

    def double_click(self):
        print("double")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    w.raise_()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: The `qApp` import is wrong, and it should be `super().mouseReleaseEvent(e)`.

Comment: Thank you. Why is `qApp` import wrong?

Comment: It should really only be in the `QtWidgets` module, not `QtCore`. PyQt5, PyQt4 and PySide do not have `qApp` in `QtCore` and the [qt docs for qApp](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#qApp) show that `qApp` should only ever return a `QApplication` (which is obviously a widget, so it makes no sense for it to be in `QtCore`). According to issue [PYSIDE-571](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/PYSIDE-571?jql=text%20~%20qapp), it seems that PySide2 has decided to be incompatible with Qt5. I have made a comment there to question that decision, and will report back if there is any response.